# PhoneGap create.bat fails

Tags: cordova

I am trying to setup PhoneGap on a new Windows machine.  Downloads and installs all go fine. In a command prompt I type `java`, `adb`, `android` and they respond correctly, but when I run the `ant` command it gives me a

`build.xml is missing`

error.  Im not quite sure where to go from here, as I have my JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME variables all set.  When I run `create.bat` with the variables

`<project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name>`

it says I am missing either JDK, Android SDK, or Apache Ant.  This is using the PhoneGap 2.6 download, eclipse, and Win7

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't make this clear, but you may need to manually install Apache Ant and/or configure additional environment variables. See http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html for instructions and hints.

Answer (score 0):

It says build.xml is missing because you are running the Ant command in a directory without a build.xml file.  Try navigating to `cordova-android/framework/` dir and then type `ant` to test if ant is installed and correctly listed in your PATH. If it is correctly installed, it should print out a bunch of stuff. This is not the way that you should be creating a Cordova project though; instead you should navigate to `cordova-android/bin` and type `create ../myTestProject com.me.test TestProject`. Also, if you pull the code directly from github instead of using the Phonegap 2.6 download, the create script [will tell you what dependency you are missing.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/36c33a58892f49067f4d3edf51b401b4a3c94259)